# Attaching a custom alert view above the iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uialertview

I'm trying to design (a "properly designed," not "hack") custom alert view. The view should attach itself to the top of the keyboard; sliding up with the keyboard (if there is an alert) or being hidden (if there is no alert).

The view should always "stick" to the keyboard... including, for instance, when the keyboard hides. In that case, the view should slide right down, out of sight, along with the keyboard.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve (with an active alert):

[image: Custom alert view above keyboard]

I have originally thought about subclassing UIAlertView, but it looks like that is not recommended. And, after experimenting a bit, this is clearly a tricky task. I've got an alert that shows up but, it turns into problems staying in sync with the keyboard, and I haven't found a way to make it "track" with the motion of the keyboard... not smoothly.

Any ideas?

Comment: i went through something similar recently ... my solution was to use a simple UIView (for the alert) and register for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` in which the UIView (for the alert) was sliding up / down (frame's origin change) with animation tied to the keyboard movement. Have you tried something similar? The notification gives you all you need (keyboard height, animation duration, etc.)

Comment: set as accessoryView.

Comment: David, yes – I was doing something similar but earlier today stumbled upon the inputAccessoryView. I had actually implemented a basic UIView that essentially did what you described... but had glitches.

The inputAccessoryView works great and iOS handles most (all?) of the animation. Pretty much I just have to take care of drawing a rectangle with my alert in it, or hiding it (as appropriate).

Comment: @Zac: i wasn't aware of accessoryView, will try that too, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with `inputAccessoryView` of `UITextField` and `UITextView`. See [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) chapter in Apple's "Text Programming Guide for iOS" for more information.

For example, a very simple red bar above the keyboard can be added with the following code:

```
let keyboardAlertView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44))
keyboardAlertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardAlertView
```